# nginx nested location with regex

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to apply HTTP auth to most of my site with the exception of the homepage, the path `/welcome` and separate /admin/, /services/ and /stats/ sections.

I don't appear to be doing this properly; here is my current config:

```
location ~ ^/(admin|services|stats)/ {   # L1
    # don't need http auth at this path as there is separate auth
    proxy_pass          http://myapp-admin-cluster;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}

location / {  #L2
    location ~ /(?!welcome).+ {   #L3
        auth_basic "MyApp";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/myapp/htpasswd;
    }
    proxy_pass          http://myapp-web-cluster;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

The problem is if I navigate to `/admin/` I get HTTP 404, rather than my request being forwarded to the myapp-admin-cluster proxy (and it also doesn't get forwarded to the myapp-web-cluster proxy).

Q1: Why doesn't the proxy settings defined in the L2 body get applied to paths matching L3?

Q2: Why does the nested location L3 override L1? They are both regex matches so surely it should match the first one?  Quote from nginx doc: "Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match"

Comment: How do you know it is matching "L3" and not matching "L1" but still getting a 404? Have you check the logs to confirm that?

Comment: Yes have looked at nginx access.log and error.log; at /admin/ nothing gets passed through to myapp-admin-cluster or myapp-web-cluster, but I get prompted for the HTTP auth and you can see in error.log that the 404 is because it ends up looking for `/usr/local/nginx/html/admin/index.html`

Comment: So you're asking the wrong questions. Before you can work out the locations you need to fix why it isn't doing `proxy_pass` because otherwise it doesn't matter about locations. Please post full configs,Have you got any other configs? specifically what config is the default.

Comment: Q1. [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104731/directive-inheritance-in-nested-location-blocks#answer-32126596)

Answer (score 1):

Because basically the *location /* will match any url pattern, so when you cannot match the admin string, you will match the rule under the / block.

From your rule L3, you match all the pages except matching */welcome*, so you will have redirected to perform basic authentication.

**UPDATE:**
As the author has updated his question, the location block should be updated and I also suspect Nginx cannot find the which file should be displayed when doing redirect, I suggest to put an *index section* too:

```
location ~* ^/(admin|services|stats)/ {
    index index.html;
    ...
```

Since you are making proxy with the url, you need to have the corresponding file under *http://myapp-admin-cluster*

For example, we have following URL:

```
http://<your_webserver_IP or DNS>/admin/1.html
```

You will be redirected to:

```
http://myapp-admin-cluster/admin/1.html
```

But not:

```
http://myapp-admin-cluster/
```

Hope it will give you to have some hints to solve your problem.

Comment: Apologies, I've simplified my example from the real world, L1 is actually more like `location ~ /(admin|services|stats)/ {` I've updated my question to reflect this in case it matters.

Comment: And yes, have just tested, and that simplified `location /admin/` doesn't have the problem that I asked in Q2

Comment: So can you simply change the location value from `location /admin/` to `location /(admin|services|stats)/` to see if it works?

Comment: `location /(admin|services|stats)/` doesn't match any of those paths because it's missing the tilde so isn't trying to do regex matching. The unexpected behavior(Q2) is that when there's a regex at L1, it gets overridden by the regex at L3 .

Comment: `http://myapp-admin-cluster/` is not a problem, it's all hooked up fine when the L3 block is absent.